# Add username and password to Mongo and access it via Hibernate

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to setup username and passowrd for mongodb.

Though i am able to set it up,it is not mandatory.

I followed http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Comment: Have you started `mongod` with the `--auth` flag set?

Comment: I solved it,i had to restart it after setting username passowrd